# Stopping Countdown using button in javascript in another function

Tags: javascript, countdown

I am having a countdown in javascript and a button which will pause/stop the countdown.

> {
>     "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined",
>     "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
>     "lineno": 57,
>     "colno": 17
>   }

```js
function start() {
  var table = document.getElementById("test");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.colSpan = 2;

  var countDownDate = new Date("Apr 30, 2019 11:12:27").getTime();


  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);




    cell1.innerHTML = seconds;

    //document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    //+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      cell1.innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(x);
}
```

```html
<table id="test" class="table table-bordered table-responsive">

</table>
<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
```

I know it can be stopped in the same function, but it is just an example, in my real code, it has to be stopped outside the function.

How to set **`x`**  so that it works outside the function too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `x` is not defined out the function `start`, so function `stop` don't see it.
Easy way to solve it, declare `x` global.

```js
var x;
function start() {
  var table = document.getElementById("test");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.colSpan = 2;

  var countDownDate = new Date("Apr 30, 2019 11:12:27").getTime();


  // Update the count down every 1 second
  x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);




    cell1.innerHTML = seconds;

    //document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    //+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      cell1.innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(x);
}
```

```html
<table id="test" class="table table-bordered table-responsive">

</table>
<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Your answer worked as I want, a small help from you, can [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/ryq96ppq/1/) javascript simplified in one line?

Comment: Sure, you can use the newer version of js like this 
`const timeoutSetter = (arr)=>arr.forEach(classNameId=>document.getElementById(classNameId).setAttribute('class', 'timeout'));` then call this function like this `timeoutSetter(["A1","B1","C1","D1"])` I prefer this two lines to just one line. declare function and call it. @Raja

Answer (score 0):

Just declare it at the top of the script so that each function can reference it:

```js
var x;
function start() {
  var table = document.getElementById("test");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.colSpan = 2;

  var countDownDate = new Date("Apr 30, 2019 11:12:27").getTime();


  // Update the count down every 1 second
  x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);




    cell1.innerHTML = seconds;

    //document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    //+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      cell1.innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(x);
}
```

```html
<table id="test" class="table table-bordered table-responsive">

</table>
<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
```

But it would be better to avoid global namespace pollution, so you could achieve that by also wrapping the whole thing in an IIFE and attaching the listeners properly with Javascript rather than in the HTML: (inline event handlers are as bad as `eval`)

```js
(() => {
  let x;
  const [startButton, stopButton] = [...document.querySelectorAll('button')];
  startButton.onclick = start;
  stopButton.onclick = stop;
  function start() {
    var table = document.getElementById("test");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.colSpan = 2;

    var countDownDate = new Date("Apr 30, 2019 11:12:27").getTime();


    // Update the count down every 1 second
    x = setInterval(function() {

      // Get todays date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now an the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);




      cell1.innerHTML = seconds;

      //document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
      //+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        cell1.innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  function stop() {
    clearInterval(x);
  }
})();
```

```html
<table id="test" class="table table-bordered table-responsive">

</table>
<button>Start</button>
<button>Stop</button>
```